# Add sub-aggregation to bucket_selector aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

So I have this query with two levels of aggregation and filter aggregation named `timestamps_bucket_filter`

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "timestamps": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "1m",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "timestamps_bucket_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "counterts": "_count"
                },
                "script": {
                  "lang": "expression",
                  "script": "counterts <= 50"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is to add another sub-aggregation below `timestamps_bucket_filter`, something like:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "timestamps": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "1m",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "timestamps_bucket_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "counterts": "_count"
                },
                "script": {
                  "lang": "expression",
                  "script": "counterts <= 50"
                }
              },
              "aggregations": {                <-- I would like to add this aggregation
                "name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "name"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting `Aggregation [timestamps_bucket_filter] cannot define sub-aggregations`

Is there any workaround for that barrier. I am really need to get those names under the filter-script I have created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a defect.  A novice reading of the docs claims to say the exact opposite:

> The interesting part comes next. Since each bucket effectively defines a document set (all documents belonging to the bucket), one can potentially associate aggregations on the bucket level, and those will execute within the context of that bucket. This is where the real power of aggregations kicks in: aggregations can be nested!

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html